# iOS Photos - can you paste copied photo

Tags: ios, photos.app

I seem to be doing a lot of long press -> Copy of Images, and I would like to save them directly into Photos, but I can't find a place to do a paste.

Instead, I have to paste into Notes, then use "Share" (Activity button) to tap "Save Image".

Is there some way to paste directly into (a new) Photo?

Answer (score 8):

Here’s a Shortcut to save the current photo from the clipboard to your Camera Roll:

- [<sub>[image]</sub> **Save Clipboard Photo**](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/0d50546004f949398a87ac1fcbd8b3a4)

  [image]

With a photo on your clipboard, call this shortcut from the Shortcuts app, or Notifications widget, or with Siri, and the clipboard photo will be added to your Camera Roll.

Answer (score 4):

No there isn't a way to copy directly into the Photos App. Using the 'share' button then selecting save is the way to add pictures to Photos.  Where are you copying the pictures from?  You can use the share icon in other apps like Safari, Mail, Messages, etc. to save directly to Photos instead of copying, then pasting in notes then using the share icon to save.

Answer (score 1):

Open Messages, address a text to yourself, tap the input bar and paste the photo, then hold a finger over the photo and choose save to save it to the camera roll.

Comment: I like that better than creating a Note just to save the Photo (note, make sure you don't accidentally send it to the wrong person :)